# io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/internal/gherkin/ast/Node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit

When I have run my below snippets by using Run as 'JUnit Test'.I am facing the below error message PFA

```
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    
    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features= {"src/test/resources/AppFeatures"},
            glue= {"stepdefinitions", "AppHooks"},
            plugin= {"pretty",
                    "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                    "timeline:test-output-thread/"
                    
            }   //pretty keyword used for printing purpose
            )
    
    
    
    public class MyTestRunner {
    
    }
```

[image: the stack trace]

Comment: Have you added `extent.properties` under feature files directory?

Comment: Yes  Nandan A,I have added

Comment: What you have written inside that?

Comment: serenity.project.name=Serenity and Cucumber Quick Start By Sachin-I have written this. can u please share your extent.properties

Comment: `serenity.project.name=Serenity and Cucumber Quick Start By Sachin` what is this? Share your code of extent reports?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Beforeclass and Afterclass hooks? If yes, please share them.

If not, please try changing glue path to:

```
glue = "stepdefinitions"
```

Glue path is supposed to specify the path to step definitions only.